# Iterable Method Batch Apex

Tags: apex, batch

I have this code -->

```
global class ExpiryDateBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global final Date startDate;
    global final Date EndDate;
    global final Integer batchLimit;

    global ExpiryDateBatchClass(Date sd,Date ed,Integer l){
        StartDate=sd;
        EndDate=ed;
        batchLimit =50;
    }

    global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        List<IPfolio__Renewal__c> renewals = [SELECT Id FROM IPfolio__Renewal__c WHERE IPfolio__IP_Right__r.IPfolio__AppDate__c!=null and IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Split_Entity__c='BIIB' and IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Responsible__c='YES' and  IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Eligible__c ='YES' and IPFolio__IP_Right__r.IPfolio__IPR_Type__c in ('Patent','Design','Utility Model','Defensive Publication') and IPfolio__Due_Date__c >=: startDate AND IPfolio__Due_Date__c <=:endDate];
        return renewals; 
    }

    public static void executeBatch(Database.Batchable batch) {

        Database.BatchableContext BC = new Database.BatchableContext();
        Iterable<sObject> iterator = batch.start(BC);
        List<Object> items = new List<Object>();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            items.add(iterator.next());
            if(items.size()==batchLimit) {
                batch.execute(BC,items);
                items.clear();
            }
        }
        batch.finish(BC);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
        //List<IPfolio__Renewal__c> renewals = (IPfolio__Renewal__c) renewals;
        for(sObject renObj : scope)
        {
            Id results = renObj.Id;
            //IPfolio__Renewal__c result=renObj.Id;


            //System.debug(renewal.Id);
            System.debug('---result---'+results);
            Database.executeBatch(new BatchQuotesRequest(startDate, results));


        }



    }


    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
    }    
}
```

It shows this error:

> Type arguments must be supplied for parameterized type : Database.Batchable

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the [using batch apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) before you move to `Iterable`.

> If you use an iterable, the governor limit for the total number of
>   records retrieved by SOQL queries is still enforced.

You can change your `start` method like this.

```
global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   Integer count = Limits.getLimitQueryRows() - Limits.getQueryRows();
   return [SELECT Id 
          FROM IP__Renewal__c 
          WHERE IP__IP_Right__r.IP__AppDate__c!=null 
            AND IP__IP_Right__r.Split_Entity__c='BIIB' 
            AND IP__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Responsible__c='YES' 
            AND IP__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Eligible__c ='YES' 
            AND IP__IP_Right__r.IP__IPR_Type__c IN ('Patent','Design','Utility Model','Defensive Publication') 
            AND IP__Due_Date__c >=: startDate 
            AND IP__Due_Date__c <=:endDate
          LIMIT :count];
}
```

You can also use the iterable to create your own custom process for iterating through the list. Have a look at [using custom iterator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm).